# What is the difference between host and domain in dig?

Tags: dns, dig

When running `dig` you can specify a "server" (the DNS server you make query against), "domain" and "host". Since "host" is not optional, I'm guessing this is what you are trying to resolve. But you also can specify a "domain". I thought that may be if we take `unix.stackexchange.com` as an example, the "host" could be `unix` and the "domain" could be `stackexchange.com`, however `dig stackexchange.com unix` did not seem to retreive the dns records for `unix.stackexchange.com`.

The "host" and "domain" I'm referring to are what is listed in the help lines below.

(To clarify, I know that `dig unix.stackexchange.com` works, I'm asking about the meaning of "host" and "domain" in dig help lines)

```
$ dig -v
DiG 9.16.44-Debian
$ dig -h
Usage:  dig [@global-server] [domain] [q-type] [q-class] {q-opt}
            {global-d-opt} host [@local-server] {local-d-opt}
            [ host [@local-server] {local-d-opt} [...]]
Where:  domain    is in the Domain Name System
        q-class  is one of (in,hs,ch,...) [default: in]
        q-type   is one of (a,any,mx,ns,soa,hinfo,axfr,txt,...) [default:a]
                 (Use ixfr=version for type ixfr)
        q-opt    is one of:
                 -4                  (use IPv4 query transport only)
                 -6                  (use IPv6 query transport only)
                 -b address[#port]   (bind to source address/port)
                 -c class            (specify query class)
                 -f filename         (batch mode)
                 -k keyfile          (specify tsig key file)
                 -m                  (enable memory usage debugging)
                 -p port             (specify port number)
                 -q name             (specify query name)
                 -r                  (do not read ~/.digrc)
                 -t type             (specify query type)
                 -u                  (display times in usec instead of msec)
                 -x dot-notation     (shortcut for reverse lookups)
                 -y [hmac:]name:key  (specify named base64 tsig key)
        d-opt    is of the form +keyword[=value], where keyword is:
                 +[no]aaflag         (Set AA flag in query (+[no]aaflag))
                 +[no]aaonly         (Set AA flag in query (+[no]aaflag))
...
        global d-opts and servers (before host name) affect all queries.
        local d-opts and servers (after host name) affect only that lookup.
        -h                           (print help and exit)
        -v                           (print version and exit)
```

Comment: Please put your full not-working command for debugging.
dig stackexchange.com unix <my local DNS IP address>
works just fine for me.

Comment: @davolfman I created a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150280/discussion-what-is-the-difference-between-host-and-domain-in-dig) to discuss further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a bug in the description introduced by [a refactoring done 23 years ago](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/commit/9fe3676b8490319aa65182f2072cbf5086097979). The help text went from the grammatically correct:

```
"Usage:  dig [@server] [domain] [q-type] [q-class] {q-opt} {d-opt}\n"
"where:  server,\n"
"        domain   are in the Domain Name System\n"
```

to this (note how it still says "are in the Domain Name System", but now the subject is the singular "domain"):

```
"Usage:  dig [@global-server] [domain] [q-type] [q-class] {q-opt}\n"
"        {global-d-opt} host [@local-server] {local-d-opt}\n"
"        [ host [@local-server] {local-d-opt} [...]]\n"
"Where:  domain   are in the Domain Name System\n"
```

If you inspect the changes, you'll see that they are all almost entirely for changing how options are assigned (globally vs per-lookup), and the code for selecting the host/domain/name/whatever-you-call-it to be looked up is itself unchanged. It did not add any new domain vs host distinction in the parsing itself. I suppose the author of the commit got the terms mixed up as it seems they were also working on `host` at around the same time (and `host` used "hostname").

This change predates the `dig(1)` manpage itself, which came [a few months later](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/blob/69f2a57302bd071a5ab41f8bab10b10be4f0c807/bin/dig/dig.1). The manpage avoids the "domain", "host" and "hostname" labels in favour of a fourth label "name", using the simpler `[@server] ... [name] [type] [class] [queryopt...]` format still seen there.

Comment: I think you are spot on

Answer (score -1):

Dig's optional `host` argument is the name of a local computer you want to send the query to.  It is not the "host" portion of a fully-qualified domain name.  (I.e., not `unix` from `unix.stackexchange.com`). The `domain` argument is the name you want to look up. (I.e., `unix.stackexchange.com`)

So if your local DNS resolver computer is named "mydns", then a `dig` query for the addresses for the name `unix.stackexchange.com` would be:

```
dig unix.stackexchange.com mydns
```

although it's usually more like:

```
dig @mydns unix.stackexchange.com
```

Or, if you want `dig` to ask your computer's default resolver (which could be a process on the same computer), it can be as simple as:

```
dig unix.stackexchange.com
```

which for me returned:

```
% dig unix.stackexchange.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> unix.stackexchange.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34418
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;unix.stackexchange.com.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
unix.stackexchange.com. 300 IN  A   172.64.144.30
unix.stackexchange.com. 300 IN  A   104.18.43.226

;; Query time: 25 msec
;; SERVER: 2001:558:feed::1#53(2001:558:feed::1)
;; WHEN: Mon Dec 11 23:17:58 PST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 83
```

Comment: Do you have an example output for `dig unix.stackexchange.com mydns`? That's how `nslookup` does things and something like `nslookup unix.stackexchange.com resolver1.opendns.com` works fine, but I can't get `dig unix.stackexchange.com resolver1.opendns.com` to work like that (it just resolves both domains using my system's configured DNS server).

Comment: I just invoked `dig @8.8.8.8 unix.stackexchange.com` and it gave me pretty much the same output as the last part of my answer.  The syntax with `mydns` as the last argument is non-standard and I don't know when/why you would use that syntax instead of the standard `dig @server fqdn` syntax.

Comment: I want to verify that this non-standard syntax works _at all_.

Comment: Notably `dig unix.stackexchange.com mydns` never worked and is not working for me as you describe it.  It executes a query for `unix.stackexchange.com` and another one for `mydns` and is exactly what I'd expect it do. I think this answer is wrong, at least for dig based on <https://github.com/isc-projects/bind9>. You may have mixed it up with nslookup, which does work the way you described.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I was interpreting the meaning of the man page you posted.  The man page on my Ubuntu 20.04 has a different description of the arguments.  Since you're not asking about the command `dig stackexchange.com unix` anymore, perhaps this is best framed as a different question, like "What is the man page's `host [@local-server] {local-d-opt}` argument for and how does it work?"

Comment: @SottoVoce the text from the question is not from the manpage, but from `dig` itself (with the `-h` option, for example). The relevant part of the text hasn't changed for 23 years, and for all of those 23 years, the manpage has had a different description which didn't mention such an argument.